# Arbitrary container around a tikzcd diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I wish to draw a picture like this with an arbitrary shape around a few points with arrows between them. I am using the circle command in tikzpicture but the result is very different. Could someone guide me?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for ... `tikzmark`!

[image]

Basic idea: make your `tikzcd` as usual. But place a `tikzmark` in the middle. I placed one on an invisible (`phantom`) arrow from `a` to `f` and called it `middleL`.

Then leave some space and make your `tikzpicture` as usual. But place a `tikzmark` in the middle. I put one at `(0,0)` and called it `middleR`.

Then start a new `tikzpicture` using `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]`. Draw big puffy cloud nodes (using `shapes.symbols`) and place them at coordinates using the syntax `(pic cs:middleL)` and `(pic cs:middleR)` (which is how to refer to previous `tikzmark`s). Then just treat them like ordinary nodes—`label` them and `\draw` an arrow between them with `bend left`.

**Note: You must compile twice when using tikzmark.**

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{elnode/.style={draw, ellipse, dotted, minimum height=1cm, label distance=-2mm},
    cloudnode/.style={draw, dashed, black!80, inner sep=1.75cm, cloud, cloud puffs=20, cloud puff arc=120}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex, outer sep=-1.5pt},row sep=1cm, column sep=2cm]
 & b\arrow[dd,bend left=20,"f"{name=F}]\\
a\arrow[ur,bend left,"g_1"]\arrow[ur,"g_2"]\arrow[ur,bend right,"g_3"]
    \arrow[dr,bend left=20,"h_1"']\arrow[dr,bend right=20,"h_2"'] 
    \arrow[to=F,phantom,"{}\tikzmark{middleL}"] \\
 & c
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{3.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\small]
\node[elnode,label={above:$C(a,b)$}] at(0,1){$g_1\quad g_2\quad g_3$};
\node[elnode,label={below:$C(a,c)$}] at (0,-1){$h_1\quad h_2$};
\node at (0,0){\tikzmark{middleR}{}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[cloudnode, label={above:$C$}](lft) at (pic cs:middleL){};
\node[cloudnode, label={above:\textbf{Set}}](rgt) at (pic cs:middleR){};
\draw[-latex](lft)to[bend left]node[above]{$C(a,-)$}(rgt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And incidently, you managed to do all the work for OP, that's very nice of you ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Follow up question: how to ensure that each of the diagrams gets a cloud? When I write a similar code for a few diagrams on the same page, only the last one gets the clouds when typeset.

Comment: @concordepi: Did you give each `tikzmark` a different name? Did you try compiling again? If those aren't the issues you may want to post a new question with your code. Please remember, on this site you should always post a complete MWE. You will rarely get help if you just post a picture and ask for assistance without providing your code. You can also reference this earlier question when you post your new one.