# Error using tikzmark with multiple tikzcd's

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, pgfmath, tikzmark

I wish to create a figure like the one shown below.

[image]

I am getting the error above with the following code. Can someone tell me where I may be going wrong?

```
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex, outer sep=-1.5pt},row sep=1cm, column sep=2cm]
& A \arrow[r, "f"] \arrow[to=F,phantom,"{}\tikzmark{catA}"] & B \arrow[d, "g"] \arrow[rd, "h"'{name=F}]\\
& C               
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{2.5cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex, outer sep=-1.5pt},row sep=1cm, column sep=2cm]
& F(A) \arrow[to=Ff,phantom,"{}\tikzmark{catop}"]  & F(B) \arrow[l, "F(f)"'] \arrow[rd, "h"'{name=Ff}\\
& F(C) \arrow[u, "F(g)"'] \arrow[lu, "F(g \circ f)"]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[cloudnode1, label={left:$\cat{A}$}](lft) at (pic cs:catA){};
\node[cloudnode1, label={right:$\cat{B}$}](rgt) at (pic cs:catop){};
\draw[-latex, black!80, bend left = 10](lft)to node[above]{F}(rgt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE. Please, always provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).
The very first error I got adding package `tikz-cd` was:
`Package pgf Error: No shape named 'F' is known. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-2`. It seems you are trying to use "F" **before** defining it. `cloudnode1` also seems to be not defined.

Comment: A more descriptive title for your question will generally get faster assistance. I suggest "Help using tikzmark with tikz-cd" or something like that. Also, always post complete code that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please, correct the title of your question: `Package pgf Error...` instead of `Package pdf Error...`.

Answer (score 4):

First, get the commutative diagrams to look the way you want before you mess with `tikzmark` and `cloud`s:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex},row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
 a \arrow[r, "f"]\arrow[rd, "g\circ f"'] & b \arrow[d, "g"]\\
& c               
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{2.5cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex},row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
F(a)   & F(b) \arrow[l, "F(f)"'] \\
& F(c) \arrow[u, "F(g)"'] \arrow[lu, "F(g \circ f)"]
\end{tikzcd}
```

Then, once those are correct, add a `tikzmark` in the center of the left diagram. I think a good spot would be along the arrow from `a` to `c`, but on the top side. So change the code for the `rd` arrow to

`\arrow[rd, "g\circ f"', "\tikzmark{catA}"]`

Now you have a `tikzmark` named `catA` that you can use later. To test the position, make a new `tikzpicture` using `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]`, which allows you to refer to earlier `tikzmarks`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[cloudnode1, label={above:$C$}](lft) at (pic cs:catA){};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am assuming that in your preamble you have defined the style `cloudnode1` using code similar to:

```
\tikzset{cloudnode1/.style={draw, dashed, black!80, inner sep=1cm,
    cloud, cloud puffs=10, cloud puff arc=150}}
```

which I adapted from [this earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640262/125871). By the way, you should always cite other people's work when you post code on this site.

**Remember you must compile twice!** The result is this:

[image]

So far so good. Now you need to do the same thing on the other diagram. Change the `lu` arrow to:

`\arrow[lu, "F(g \circ f)", "\tikzmark{catop}"']`

Add the line

`\node[cloudnode1, label={above:$B$}](rgt) at (pic cs:catop){};`

to the `tikzpicture` and...

[image]

Looks like the clouds are too small. Increase the `inner sep` to `1.3cm` or whatever looks good to you. Finally, add

`\draw[-latex, black!80, bend left = 10, dashed](lft)to node[above]{$F$}(rgt);`

and adjust the space between the two clouds. **Remember to compile twice!**

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{cloudnode1/.style={draw, dashed, black!80, inner sep=1.3cm, cloud, cloud puffs=10, cloud puff arc=150}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex},row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
 a \arrow[r, "f"]\arrow[rd, "g\circ f"', "\tikzmark{catA}"] & b \arrow[d, "g"]\\
& c               
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{3cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex},row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
F(a)   & F(b) \arrow[l, "F(f)"'] \\
& F(c) \arrow[u, "F(g)"'] \arrow[lu, "F(g \circ f)", "\tikzmark{catop}"']
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[cloudnode1, label={above:$C$}](lft) at (pic cs:catA){};
\node[cloudnode1, label={above:$B$}](rgt) at (pic cs:catop){};
\draw[-latex, black!80, bend left = 10, dashed](lft)to node[above]{$F$}(rgt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As a final thought, you might want to increase the `row sep` and `column sep` on the left diagram so it has the same size as the right one.

`\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex},row sep=1.3cm, column sep=1.3cm]`

Then the result is:

[image]

which looks quite nice to me.